# MS Project Dynamic Portfolio Reporting

Tags: reporting

I have a team creating projects in MS Project. I need them to share their projects with me (in sharepoint?) so I can pull individual reports in real time.  I then need to take those dynamic projects and put them into a master that I can report on from the Portfolio level.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: I'm nor clear what the real question is here.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a team creating projects in MS Project. I need them to share their projects with me (in sharepoint?)

You should establish a shared network location where your team will drop their up-to-date Project files on a regular cadence (maybe every day, once per week, etc.) that works for you. I don't recommend using SharePoint because people will sometimes get hung-up on the whole "check-in/check-out" system SharePoint offers and MS Project files should really be worked off user's local machine, not the network or web (especially if your team is working remote and connecting to the network through a VPN).

> I then need to take those dynamic projects and put them into a master
> that I can report on from the Portfolio level.

MS Project has a built in way of integrating multiple subproject files into a single master schedule but this feature, in my opinion, is **terrible** and can end up causing a bunch of issues in the files and eventually corrupting them. There are some third party tools that can help you integrate multiple projects in a much better, less risky way than what MS Project offers. [Here is one example](https://ssitools.com/multiple-project-management-tools/).

Answer (score 0):

Workzone is a SharePoint alternative that is used by a variety of companies because its structure can be changed to fit their needs. Excellent training and support are included in the Workzone system. This means that teams who utilize this program will be able to take advantage of all of its features, such as:

- Secure file sharing

  Approvals workflow

  Comment features

  Task sharing

  Work is documented as it’s done

> *I then need to take those dynamic projects and put them into a master that I can report on from the Portfolio level.*

Asana is an option. Asana is a popular project management tool that can also be used to manage multiple projects. You can select from a variety of useful templates for each project, including a content calendar, meeting agenda, team goals and objectives planning, corporate strategy plan, and more. Different views can be used to visualize your workflow in each project.

Asana's task pane includes Microsoft Sharepoint, which may be used to share files with the team. In a nutshell, Sharepoint may be used to organize, store, distribute, and access data from a variety of devices. Users can directly connect files from Sharepoint to tasks once Asana has been integrated. Because both are Microsoft products, it works in the same manner that users attach files from OneDrive.